# Open pdf file on the secondary monitor using vba

Tags: vba, pdf, multiple-monitors

I am trying to make a program that opens a pdf file on the secondary monitor on a dual monitor setup. I have a working program from opening the file, but it always opens on the primary monitor. I want the pdf to automatically open on the secondary monitor. Is this possible?

Thank you for all help.

Comment: are you open to using a utility to do this for you (I do something like this with [ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/))  Otherwise I think you're going to have to use winapi calls to do it.  Like this to get the window handle: [link](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/04/open-pdf-file-with-vba.html) and then figure out how to get the window to the right screen with some other calls: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx)